# How to post to user's wall from application's name?

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I tried to post to users wall using application access token but it still posts from users name. Is it possible to post from application's name?

```
var fbc = new FacebookWebClient();
        var wc = new WebClient();
        var tokenStr = wc.DownloadString(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials",
            FacebookApplication.Current.AppId, FacebookApplication.Current.AppSecret));

        fbc.AccessToken = tokenStr.Replace("access_token=", string.Empty);

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = "testMessage";
        //parameters.link = pageLink;
        parameters.name = "testCaption";

        dynamic result = fbc.Post(string.Format("{0}/feed", userID), parameters);
```

Comment: No, apps themselves are not “persons” who can act that way on the platform. The closest possible thing IMHO would be a fan page for your app – that could have posts on it’s own wall appear in every fan’s stream automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fbPost = new FacebookClient ( accessToken );
         dynamic result = fbPost.Post ( "me/feed", new { message = "Welcome to C# SDK and me" } );
```